# Why does Multi-stage docker build get stuck at "COPY --from=builder ..."

Tags: docker, jenkins, kubernetes, docker-in-docker

The context is as follows:

- Jenkins
- Kubernetes plugin
- Docker-in-Docker/dind container
- Multi-stage Dockerfile

The flow looks as follows:

1. pull builder `docker pull repo/image:builder`
2. build builder `DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build . --build-arg BUILDKIT_INLINE_CACHE=1 --target builder --cache-from repo/image:builder --tag repo/image:builder`
3. push builder `docker push repo/image:builder`
4. pull image `docker pull repo/image:tag`
5. build image `DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build . --build-arg BUILDKIT_INLINE_CACHE=1 --cache-from repo/image:builder --cache-from repo/image:tag --tag repo/image:tag`
6. push image `docker push repo/image:tag`

Dockerfile:

```sh
FROM node:8.16.0 as builder

WORKDIR /app
RUN mkdir /app/frontend
COPY frontend/package.json /app/frontend/
WORKDIR /app/frontend
RUN npm install
COPY frontend /app/frontend
RUN npm run build
FROM nginx:1.13.8-alpine
WORKDIR /project/web
COPY --from=builder --chown=nginx:nginx /app/frontend/built /project/web/public
```

At `COPY --from=builder --chown=nginx:nginx /app/frontend/built /project/web/public` the docker build gets stuck forever(30-40 min after which I stop it manually) without error.

EDIT: At the first run, when images are not yet present in the registry, builder caching and `COPY --from=builder` works as expected. Only from the second build onwards does it get stuck at `COPY --from=builder`